# Variable content not displayed in http request - jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I created a test plan that just send request parse the response and create another request.

the problem is that in one of the variable I do not see it sent its content, the request is ok, I parsed the field that I want (nurl) using json path extractor and than using regex to get the value (iid) from the (nurl).

I put the value in a variable and saw in debug that it was parsed ok,
when I create a new HTTP request and passed this value as a variable it displayed null.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

[image: test plan]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `json path extractor` and than using `regex` to get the value should be for `HTTP request SITE - IOS` so I suggest you put all those **under** `HTTP request SITE - IOS` (and not in same hierarchy) so it'll be executed only once after response received. (You can mark all extractor and drag and drop as a child of HTTP request)

Currently you execute it for every Sampler in hierarchy including Debug Sampler which will make the variable null.

Answer (score 0):

After checking I just unmarked the 'use empty as default value' at the regex and it worked,